# Microsoft Azure SDK 2.8 for VS 2015 failed to Install

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-sdk-.net, web-platform-installer

I tried to install Microsoft Azure SDK for VS 2015 using Web Platform installer 5.0.  Installation failed with several dependency packages failed to download.

These are the some errors logged there.

Error: 0 : Signature verification failed on downloaded file. URL: http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/F/E/0FE64840-9806-4D3C-9C11-84B743162618/MicrosoftAzureStorageEmulator.msi.

Error: 0 : Signature verification failed on downloaded file. URL: http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/E/B/DEB395C9-C875-47F3-96F7-55C9A8FCD869/MicrosoftAzureAuthoringTools-x64.msi.

Please shed some light to solve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

--edit to remove original answer-- solution in linked thread

[There is a good thread on iis.net](https://forums.iis.net/p/1229945/2115849.aspx?Re+Install+failure+for+Azure+SDK+Azure+App+Service+Tools+v2+8+2) with a solution.

```
[Solution from iis.net by ChrisSfanos]
please delete all the .xml files from
1) %localappdata%\microsoft\web platform installer
2) %localappdata%\microsoft\web platform installer\preprocessor
```

Then restart the web platform installer